# store an image in internal storage in android

Tags: android, image, sd-card

I am working now on application that start the camera and take a photo, I didn't use camera activity, but I wrote my camera app and I want to save the taken image in the internal phone storage in folder called "temPic"

The following code generate the folder and the image, but when I checked the tempPic I found an image called image1.jpg and it's size is 461115 ( I tried to store the image in SDcard directory and it is the same size), but when I double clicked it a black image appeared, not the taken one although in SDcard I opened it !!!

```
FileManipulator fileFormat = new FileManipulator(
                getApplicationContext());
        String path = fileFormat.createFolder_PStrg("tempPic") + "/image1.jpg";     
        File file = new File(path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        OutputStream imageFileOS;
        try {


            imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(outputFileUri);
            imageFileOS.write(arg0);
            imageFileOS.flush();
            imageFileOS.close();
            Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, 
                    file.length()+"", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, 
                    "Image saved: " + outputFileUri.toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        camera.startPreview();
```

Comment: fileFormat.createFolder_PStrg is a method to create a folder in the internal storage

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if this can help you but this is how I save a file to the SD card and it works.

```
        public void saveToSD(Bitmap outputImage){


            File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyPhotos/"); 
            storagePath.mkdirs(); 

            File myImage = new File(storagePath, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

            try { 
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImage); 
                outputImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out); 
                out.flush();    
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }               
        }
```

Comment: Internal in this case means the SD card which is built into the device, but it is not the application private storage, which is accessed in a different way.

Comment: When using 'getExternalStorageDirectory()' (I quote) "Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer." So it may be the actual physical SD card or it might be a built-in storage.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the camera activity and save images to internal storage by creating temp folder that has writable permission which allow other application to write to this folder and take the image to its path and then after the camera activity return you can move the image to another internal storage folder but with private permission as follow

```
//the temp folder to start the camera activity with
String path = getDir("images", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE).getPath() + "/test.jpg";

//start the camera activity
File file = new File(path);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

Intent intent = new Intent(
android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_ACTIVITY);
```

and in onActivityResult method move it to folder with private permission it will work fine as I tested it