# How to save image at internal storage?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [store an image in internal storage in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766579/store-an-image-in-internal-storage-in-android)

How to save image at internal storage ? I need to be sure that user is stored image when doesn't have sdcard ( till now I have been using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to store image in EXTRA_OUTPUT ). Can anyone help, I need URI of stored image ?

Comment: I am sure this is not a preferrable to store image in internal storage, do you know about the internal storage size comes in android device? its mostly around 256MB, 512MB, etc. etc. and its used for application internal purpose, system management, etc.

Comment: Call getFilesDir() from your context
[Documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29)

Comment: I am not sure....but you can go through this..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766579/store-an-image-in-internal-storage-in-android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html

Comment: +1, @anuja provided a similar question, but there the is saving to external storage and not to internal storage. IMHO this question shouldn't be closed neither downvoted! Trying to correct the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

You can save files directly on the device’s internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them. When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

The following scriptlet will show you how to save file in android:

```
String FILENAME = "my_file";
    String string = "Schogini Systems";

    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();
```

Comment: +1,it should be accepted this answer as solution

Comment: this solution does not work for an image as getBytes() is not available for Bitmap type